# What is the command for calling the Mesh menu (accessible in Edit mode)?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to call the Mesh menu, similarly to the way that Vertex, Edge, and Face menus are bound to hotkeys. However, when I right-click the Mesh menu button, I am given no option to create a shortcut. The only option available is "Add to Quick Favorites."

By searching keymap entries, I've found that VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_faces calls the face menu, VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_edges calls the edge menu, and VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_vertices calls the vertex menu; I expect there to be a variation of this command for the mesh menu, but I don't know that it is, and my guesses haven't borne out.

VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_mesh does nothing; neither does VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry you are searching for is *VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh*. You need to add a new entry or overwrite some entry you don't use:

[image: Image from the Keymap menu]

In the future, if you want to find the Python name for some menu you just need to activate "Python tooltips" under Preferences > Interface. With this option activated, the tooltip will appear when you put your mouse over every menu.

[image: Python Tooltips]

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!